# How to fix this Google Ad Manager error: gpt.js was requested from both the standard and limited ads domains within the same page

Tags: google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

A partner of us is using our Google tags from Google Ad Manager (GAM) and suddently it stopped working. The error I have in the ?google_console is:

**Warning:**
Attempted to load GPT from both standard and limited ads domains.
Issue: gpt.js was requested from both the standard and limited ads domains within the same page.

The tags work fine on my test page, so I'm suspected that another instance of Google tags is being called on the partner's page. But in general, websites work with multiple ad network that may also use Google tags, so it shouldn't be a problem, thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The standard GPT library is loaded from:

```
https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js
```

The library for limited ads is loaded from:

```
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/tag/js/gpt.js
```

If your partner is loading both on the same page, this will cause different issues and lead to the mentioned message. It looks like your partner aims to load the limited ads library in case the user does not provide consent (but instead the library loads always), because this is a cookie-less domain which is often used as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just thinking that this scenario is probably quite common. Not sure if this would stop the ads running, but I can't see any other errors.